# Send Email With Attachment

Tags: php, function, email, header, attachment

Hi i've followed a tutorial and a couple of answers on here but still when I try to send the email with an attachment to my gmail as a test it doesn't work. The email:

African Pygmy Hedgehog Club News Letter

admin@africanpygmyhedgehogclub.co.uk via moth.xssl.net

"

> Content-Type: text/html;
>
> #### African Pygmy Hedgehog Club News
>   Letter
>
> Hello there this is a test message
>   --1575d7e57c4ae2d9bdd29f847d8f48ea
>
> Content-Type: image/jpeg; name="/tmp/php7LfGKW"
>   Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64 Content-Disposition: attachment
>   /9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAgEASABIAAD/4RNGRXhpZgAATU0AKgAAAAgABwESAAMAAAABAAEAAAEaAAUA
>   AAABAAAAYgEbAAUAAAABAAAAagEoAAMAAAABAAMAAAExAAIAAAAUAAAAcgEyAAIAAAAUAAAAhodp
>   AAQAAAABAAAAnAAAAMgAAAAcAAAAAQAAABwAAAABQWRvYmUgUGhvdG9zaG9wIDcuMAAyMDA5OjA4
>   OjA4IDIxOjE1OjA5AAAAAAOgAQADAAAAAf//AACgAgAEAAAAAQAAAligAwAEAAAAAQAAAdAAAAAA
>   AAAABgEDAAMAAAABAAYAAAEaAAUAAAABAAABFgEbAAUAAAABAAABHgEoAAMAAAABAAIAAAIBAAQA
>   AAABAAABJgICAAQAAAABAAASGAAAAAAAAABIAAAAAQAAAEgAAAAB/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAgEASABI
>   AAD/7QAMQWRvYmVfQ00AAv/uAA5BZG9iZQBkgAAAAAH/2wCEAAwICAgJCAwJCQwRCwoLERUPDAwP
>   FRgTExUTExgRDAwMDAwMEQwMDAwMDAwMDAwMDAwMDAwMDAwMDAwMDAwMDAwBDQsLDQ4NEA4OEBQO
>   ....

My Code:

```
    if(isset($_POST['send_newsletter']))
    {
    $newsletter->store_form_values($_POST);
        $emails = explode(',', $newsletter->newsletter_emails);
    $file = $_FILES;

    $send_email = $newsletter->email_newsletter($emails, $file);

        echo $send_email;
    }

    public function email_newsletter($emails, $file)
    {
        //email address from
    $from = 'admin@africanpygmyhedgehogclub.co.uk';
    //subject
    $subject = "African Pygmy Hedgehog Club News Letter";

    $random_hash = "--" .  md5(date('r', time())) . "\r\n\n";
    $boundry_last = $random_hash;

    //turn emails array into csv
    $bcc = null;
    foreach($emails as $key => $value)
    {
        if($key == 'newsletter_sign_email')
        {
        $bcc .= $value . ',';
        } 
    }

    $bcc = rtrim($bcc);

    //headers
    $headers = 'From: ' . $from . "\r\n";
    $headers .= 'Reply-To: ' . $from . "\r\n";
    $headers .= 'BCC: ' . $bcc . "\r\n";
    $headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
    $headers .= "Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=\"PHP-mixed-" . $random_hash . "\"";

    //main message body
    $message = "Content-Type: text/html;" . "\r\n";
    $message .= "<h3>African Pygmy Hedgehog Club News Letter</h3>\n\n";
    $message .= $this->formatting($this->newsletter_content) . "\r\n";
    $message .= $random_hash;

    //attachment
    $file = $file['newsletter_attachment'];
    $filename = $file['tmp_name'];
    $filecontents = file_get_contents($filename);
    $message .= "Content-Type: " . $file['type'] . "; name=\"" . $filename . "\"" . "\r\n"; 
    $message .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64" . "\r\n";  
    $message .= "Content-Disposition: attachment" . "\r\n";  
    $message .= chunk_split(base64_encode($filecontents)) . "\r\n";
    $message .= $boundry_last;

    if(mail($from, $subject, $message, $headers))
    {
    $result = "Successfully Sent News Letter";
    }
    else
    {
    $result = "Failed to Send New Letter, please try again!";
    }

    return $result;
    }
```

Comment: Use [PHPMailer](http://phpmailer.worxware.com/) to ease up your email sending process. It does a great deal of legwork for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may be able to fix your problem after reading this:

http://webcheatsheet.com/php/send_email_text_html_attachment.php

It's quite consise and to the point - though it is quite messy.

Your best option would be to use http://swiftmailer.org/ to send your emails which also supports attachments and a LOT more.

Comment: I've gone with swiftmailer and i'm impressed with how good it is and easy to use thanks for your advice

Answer (score 0):

Without running the code, it looks like the boundary between the mail message and the attachment is not being set.  It does not appear to have -

```
PHP-Mixed . . .
```

Comment: I've taken PHP-Mixed out of the boundry in the header and it still doesn't work :(

Comment: I think you should add it in as it is specified in a variable above.